# Unable to download the maven dependency from jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am running the automation suite, when i build my project on Jenkins i t is trying to download the maven dependency from maven repo, but it is getting failed due to connection refused issue.

In local i have added the proxy setting in settings file in .m2 file so on local everything works fine, now on Jenkins i tried too do the same but didn't worked

Please help me on this how to get this issue resolved, is there any way to provide the maven dependency to my Jenkins project

Comment: It will be helpful if you post you pom.xml code along with errors you are getting on Jenkins console.

Comment: Thanks saurabh for your reply, please check below error message which i am getting on jenkins

Comment: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.196.215] failed:

Comment: Are you able to connect to maven repo using curl/wget from the server where build is running/Jenkins is installed? Check that manually.
If that does not work, you have to make sure that specific server can connect to required maven repo.
If your network settings do no allow this, try to use maven in "offiline" like "mvn -o" which will try to resolve dependencies from local .m2 repo. In this case, you have to make sure all required dependencies are available locally.

Comment: Hey Saurabh, thanks for you time.

Comment: I resolved the issue by configuaring the XML file on settings of jenkins with my organization proxy settings

Comment: Good to know. I thought that has been already done as you had mentioned this :

now on Jenkins i tried too do the same but didn't worked

Comment: @saurabh14292: i tried it with wrong settings file, so it didn't worked.
but now i have struck with other thing, chrome driver plugins are downloaded but those are the latest version, i am using chrome version 55, so i need to set the path for my local chrome driver.

can you please guide me in how to set that?